# COM ADD-in,Outlook,ItemSend

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write an Office 2007 COM Add-in which will check some rules before mail is send. Below test code works but I have several warnings in VS2010 and maybe someone can help me with this.

Code below:

```
Imports Extensibility
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Microsoft.Win32



<GuidAttribute("B19F59E7-4F71-475C-9531-FB46842E5E5E"), ProgIdAttribute("DODATKI.Connect")> _
Public Class Connect

 Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2
    Dim WithEvents OutlookApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
 Private applicationObject As Object
    Private addInInstance As Object

    Public Sub OnBeginShutdown(ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnBeginShutdown
        'MsgBox("Add-in is OnBeginShutdown")
    End Sub

 Public Sub OnAddInsUpdate(ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnAddInsUpdate
 End Sub

    Public Sub OnStartupComplete(ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnStartupComplete
        MsgBox("Add-in is OnStartupComplete")
        OutlookApplication = New Outlook.Application
    End Sub

 Public Sub OnDisconnection(ByVal RemoveMode As Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode, ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnDisconnection
 End Sub

 Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode As Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode, ByVal addInInst As Object, ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection
        MsgBox("Add-in is OnConnection")
        applicationObject = application
        addInInstance = addInInst

        ' If you aren't in startup, manually call OnStartupComplete.
        If (connectMode <> Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup) Then _
           Call OnStartupComplete(custom)

 End Sub
    Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles OutlookApplication.ItemSend
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hi, You are sending message")
        Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
        Msg = Item

        If Trim(Item.Subject) = "" Then
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Cannot send message with an empty subject!!!")
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Warnings:

```
1) On Msg = Item
Warning 1 Implicit conversion from 'Object' to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'
2) On Item.Subject
Warning 2 Implicit conversion from 'Object' to 'String'
3) On Item.Subject
Warning 3 Late bound resolution; runtime errors could occur
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 1:

```
Msg = CType(Item, Outlook.MailItem)
```

About 2 and 3:

```
If Trim(Msg.Subject)
```

Another suggestion is to turn on Option Explicit and Option Strict, i.e. at the top of each file add something like

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
```

Comment: Thank You, it is ok now. Maybe You know how to open a folder that contains a comma in it's path like:
 Shell("explorer.exe \\server\path to, folder", vbHide)
or
 Shell("cmd /c start \\server\path to, folder", vbHide)

Comment: Hi Marcin. If it answers your question, you may consider marking my answer as "accepted". Also you may want to reformulate your further comment as a new question - better chance to get an answer.